# How to add and remove from list concurrently?

Tags: java, list, guava, monitor, guard

I've stumbled upon the following approach in a project, which to me doesn't look safe:

```
    public class EntityProcessor
    {

        private static final Monitor monitor = new Monitor();
        private static final List&lt;String&gt; entitiesInProcess = newArrayList();


        public processEntities(Entities entities)
        {
            for (final Entities entity : entities)
            {
                final String id = getId();

                try
                {
                    monitor.enterWhen(new Guard(monitor)
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean isSatisfied()
                        {
                            return !entitiesInProcess.contains(id);
                        }
                    });
                    entitiesInProcess.add(id);

                }
                catch (final InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally
                {
                    monitor.leave();
                }

                try
                {
                    processEntity(entity)
                }
                catch (final Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    entitiesInProcess.remove(id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To me it seems like this arraylist can get corrupted since the remove isn't guarded. 
However, I don't know how to implement it properly.
Desired state:
Use the arrayList as a control object to determine if an entity with a given id is already being processed and that the thread that wants to process an entity with the same id should therefore wait until it's no longer being processed, then start processing it (again).

Circumstances:

- Id's are given(e.g we can't create our own).
- processEntity(entity) can be called concurrently for entities with different id's.

Questions:

- Is this approach totally wrong(e.g, can't be implemented to work - redesign)?
- If not - any suggestions how to achieve the desired state?
- If - any ideas on how to redesign?

Example code is appreciated :-).

#### Update

So, I tried the set approach, which gives me a situation that if I try to process several entitities with the same ID (like 100 entities with 10 threads), some threads will hang indefintely waiting on the condition. I think there's another bug somewhere in the code that makes this happen, perhaps creating a new lock each time is problematic. So in the example above, 91 entities will get processed, while the threads look like this(the id and conditions are different for each thread:

```
    pool-2-thread-4" prio=6 tid=0x00000000285d0800 nid=0x278c waiting on condition [0x000000002935e000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000057eee67c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Monitor.waitInterruptibly(Monitor.java:831)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Monitor.enterWhen(Monitor.java:366)
```

I also tried the Collections.synchronizedList approach, additionally changing issatisfied to:

```
                public boolean isSatisfied()
                {
                    final boolean contains = entitiesInProcess.contains(entityId);
                    if (!contains)
                    {
                        entitiessInProcess.add(entityId);
                    }
                    return !contains;
                }
```

This in order to not end up in a situation that two threads try to add an entity at the same time, e.g first thread checks contains, second thread adds an entity, firsts thread also adds the same entity.

NOTE: Entity here is not the Entity class of java, perhaps it would have been better to call it Item.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not in control of the threading itself, so it is actually also a given(If I'm not mistaken), the result of a queue being polled by org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer with concurrent consumers.
                                                                           
I saw some earlier post that seems removed around using ExecutorService and maps, which I'm assessing, perhaps I would need to introduce some internal queuing to get that right?

Comment: It feels like I should use some entirely different approach, like putting everything I receive in parrallell form the different threads on some in-memory queue, then start an ExecutorCompletionService with an ExecutorService with X number of threads to process them, and keeping track of the list of currently in-process entitie there instead before submitting a new one to the ExecutorCompletionService or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is this:

```
private static final List<String> entitiesInProcess = 
    Collections.synchronizedList( newArrayList() );
```

As processEntities can be called concurrently, the single resource entitiesInProcess must be synchronized.

**However**, this (although closely following the original code) results in overengineering. What you have is one critical section `processEntity(entity)` w.r.t. the object of classs `Entity`. Thus, all you need is

```
for (final Entity entity: entities){
    synchronized( entity ){
        processEntity(entity);
    }
}
```

No List, no Monitor is required. Surrounding this with a try/catch block for InterruptedException may be a good idea, depending on whether you can handle the case within the loop or not, so I left it out.

**2nd edit**
The (weird) situation that different Entity objects may have identical `id` attributes and locking should be based on these can be handled using

```
 for (final Entity entity: entities){
    synchronized( entity.getId().intern() ){
        processEntity(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't that be problematic if the duplicate entities aren't the "same" object, but just share the id?

Comment: If there is one id (4711) given to two distinct objects, an operation on 4711a will not change 4711b, and vice versa, so I don't see any reason to block non-unique ids. Even if you wait on "4711" while 4711a is updated and then use the different(!) data in 4711b for an update of that object: how will the parallel data in 4711a and 4711b be merged or combined if these two objects represent the same real-world entity? Multiple instances of the same class (Entity) representing the same real-world thing are unusual and likely to cause more than one headache.

Comment: I have added an update to my answer that should handle "shared ids".

Comment: If you let multiple threads work on `entities` (which may or may not be what the OP does), they'll all process each entity (which is probably not wanted).

Comment: @maaartinus In the absence of a clear or concise requirements spec - who knows? I'll not look at this question again.

Answer (score 0):

Burn it and bury deep.

The way it gets accesses calls for a `Set`. The concurrency pattern just cries.

```
private static final Set<String> entitiesInProcess = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();

public void processEntities(Entities entities) {
    for (final Entity entity : entities) {
        final String id = entity.getId();
        final boolean isInProcess = !entitiesInProcess.add(id);
        if (isInProcess) continue;
        try {
            processEntity(entity);
        } finally {
            entitiesInProcess.remove(id);
        }
    }
}
```

This allows for maximum concurrency. The `Set` is based on `ConcurrentHashMap` which is a sort of collection of synchronized Maps, where the segment gets determined by the `hashCode` of the key. So it guarantees that the `add` is atomic and only one thread may get true back. Here, it gets used as a sort of map of locks.

If `processEntity` is slow, then a `synchronizedSet` would equally well, too. Otherwise, this solution is better.

Your question is tagged with Guava, so you can use `Sets`. But you could easily use a `Map<String, Whatever>` instead.

### Simplification

I guess, all you need is a `ConcurrentQueue`. Upon encountering a new entity to be processed, put it in. When a thread wants to help with the processing, let it `poll` the queue (possibly in a loop) and process the obtained `entity` (unless `null` was returned meaning there's nothing to do). *It can't get any simpler.*

Comment: Looks like an interesting approach. What happens to the entity that doesn't get processed due to the "continue" clause. It gets skipped in this solution - right?

Comment: @user2574522 It gets skipped iff `isInProcess` is true, and this can only happen if it's in the set, i.e., if there's another thread  working on it. **** Given how broken the original approach is, I wouldn't be surprised, if the proper interface would look differently, e.g., enqueuing an element for later processing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So thanks for all the input and answers. Ultimately it guided me to a working solution.

NOTE: The best solution would probably have been to burn it and bury it deep and reimplement with internal queue and ExecutorCompletionService, doing the whole duplicate check in a single scheduler thread before letting the workers import items.

The solution to the code at hand was to not exit isSatisfied() in monitor. 
Hence what solved it all was to do a loop in that method to check the condition.
I'm stuck on version 11 of guava(bundled with the product we're building our stuff on unfortunately), so for all I can see this is a bug in that version as the javadoc states that it should work with if-clause. Not optimal(given the contention on a duplicate entity) but good enough for now.